# Cisco gear - finding mac address of a device based on Ip address?

Tags: ip, mac-address

Say, I have some devices connected to cisco routers. I want to be able to query an api or something using an IP address of one of the devices, and receive back it's mac address. Is this possible? Pointers would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain this information from router's ARP cache. Logon with ssh or console and issue the following command:

```
show arp w.x.y.z
```

where w.x.y.z is the IP address of the device you are looking for.